# Can I take the Online Proctored Certification exams on a Mac running OSX (Mavericks)?

Tags: certification, mac-os-x

I've heard different answers to this, so would appreciate a definitive clarification.  Is it possible to sit an online proctored Salesforce certification exam on a Mac running OSX (Mavericks)?

[Kryterion suggests that Webassessor supports OSX](http://www.kryteriononline.com/online_exams/indexmac.asp), but I'd like to hear it from someone who's tried it personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2015, the exams can be taken on a Mac without needing a VM or Windows partition.

I've used a Logitech C310 HD Webcam for several exams now, and it works very well.  Definitely preferable to having to go to a test centre.  Just be sure to update the Sentinel software if prompted by the Webassessor site.

Answer (score 4):

I was informed by Web Assessor support that Salesforce exams are only available using Windows (despite having OS X teasing instructions).

Answer (score 0):

Although the Kryterion software loaded okay I ended up having problems with using an external webcam with my Macbook, so I ultimately used Bootcamp to load Windows 7 and then take the test on there.